# React JSX error : Unclosed regular expression

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

Recently I was facing an issue coding React app on Visual Studio code. Because of this issue, whenever I wrote JSX inside the render function of the React Component and saved it, it would go messed up (I mean indentation would get messy). See the pic:
[image]

This error was also showing error like:
1. Unclosed regular expression

How to solve this?

Answer (score 49):

If you are using `jshint` plugin, remove it and install `ESLint` plugin.

It is a good replacement for `jshint` in reactJS work.

Comment: After that you should restart the computer for cleaning RAM.

Comment: Restarting VS Code should be enough.

Comment: this solves my problem, i have the jslint install globally, and esLint extension installed in vscode

Answer (score 10):

I tried several options like creating a .eslintrc file or .jshintrc file.

But it turned out that in my Visual Studio Code IDE, there was third party extensions(eslint/jslint/tslint/beautify/jsformatter etc) that were causing a big mess in my JSX code.

I had to go to the extensions and disable all the extension which could hinder in the natural process of linting and code cleaning of React framework.

[image]

(These extensions are really great. But disabling them helped me in solving this issue of mine, no offense to anyone.)

If you are facing the same issue and the issue persists event after adding a .jshintrc with content:

```
{
    "esversion": 6
}
```

then consider disabling the third party extensions.

Hope my answer helped.

Comment: I am pretty sure it was only the formatter. Automatic formatters have many problems. And using multiple formatters at once is just not possible. Using multiple linters at once is probably unnecessary.

Comment: True it is unnecessary. I just had those linters lying out there for no reason, which was causing the issue.

Comment: ya this help me out

Comment: This answer led me to disabling JSHint which solved my issue.

Answer (score 10):

the extension that did it for me was...

### jshint

*dbaeumer.jshint*
**Dirk Baeumer**

as @abhay-shiro says, *disabling* a few extensions will usually resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but it was "beautify" extension which was causing the error, I uninstalled it and installed prettier. It fixed the problem.

Answer (score -8):

I solved this issue by disabling show syntax errors checkbox in visual studio 2015.

**Tools -> options - > text editor -> javascript -> intelliSense -> general -> show syntax errors(disable)**

Comment: This is exactly how the Chernobyl disaster happened. You don't overlook warnings, you get rid of or fix the things that caused them.